# Can I reuse a created array from a former notebook in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Can I create a reusable Numpy array in Jupyter Notebook and reuse it in another notebook?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: np.save and np.load Have you ruled those out?

Comment: Pickling can also be an option for you.